# Глобальная константная переменная

Tags: c

Нужно объявить глобальную переменную:

```
extern int SIZE_A=10;
```

Почему-то выводит предупреждение:

> ```
> warning: 'SIZE_A' initialized and declared 'extern'
> ```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Эта переменная у вас вовсе не константная :), но проблема не в этом.

Просто нормальная практика такова: в *одном* файле глобальная переменная объявлена и определена, типа

```
int SIZE_A = 10;
```

а в других (например, с помощью механизма включаемых заголовочных файлов) - только объявлено, что где-то *в другом файле* (т.е. `extern`) есть такая переменная

```
extern int SIZE_A;
```

Просто иначе вы рискуете указать разные значения этой переменной в разных файлах - о чем вас и предупреждают. При этом возможны варианты, в зависимости от компилятора, когда `extern` со значением приведет к созданию переменной в объектном файле - тогда при линковке будет коллизия - две переменные с одинаковыми именами; какую из них считать верной? или когда `extern` приведет все же только к ссылке на переменную в другом файле - но тогда будет полностью проигнорировано значение в объявлении `extern` - его просто некуда будет записать :)

Comment: а если в двух будет присвоено значение, а в третьем нет, то какое значение будет в третьем?

Comment: @Grundy UB :) Только вот нормальный компилятор просто не даст такое скомпилировать. Например, VC++ категорически отказался линковать.

Comment: интересно, но в принципе может быть любым значением? :)

Comment: @Grundy Знаете, я к этому отношусь примерно так... Есть конституция, есть куча законов, которые *теоретически* не должны противоречить конституции, но обычно на это никто не смотрит, а есть реальная проза жизни... И если пытаться жить по конституции - очень скоро такая жизнь станет пыткой :) Сюда же подходит вторая фраза - "когда я приезжаю в страну, я не спрашиваю, какие там законы. Я спрашиваю, выполняются ли они". Вероятно, я неправ, но я стараюсь 1. избегать темных углов, и 2. знать, как ведет себя мой инструмент в тех или иных случаях. Поэтому что будет в вашей ситуации? не знаю.

Comment: @Grundy Знаю, что VC++ такое вообще не даст скомпилировать, а OWatcom даст, но похерит (предупредив) значение в объявлении `extern`. Что из них более правильно - пусть решает конституционный суд :)

Comment: ну так по идее вона должна стать константной ? `extern const int SIZE_A;`

Comment: @Hardc0re Вообще-то одно то, что что-то объявлено как `extern`, уже наводит на размышления. В том плане, что в объектном файле при обращениях будет только место для адреса, грубо говоря :) В принципе, как я понимаю, компилятор - чисто теоретически - мог бы заменить просто значение `SIZE_A` на указанное значение - но ведь наличие `extern` говорит ему о том, что это очень небезопасно: как знать, что там с этим именем объявлено в другом файле? Например, нет никакого способа бороться с тем, что в одном файле это `extern const int`, а в другом - просто `double`. С тем же именем...

Answer (score 2):

В [c](/questions/tagged/c) объявление идентификатора объекта в области видимости файла, содержащее при этом инициализатор, является *внешним определением (external definition)* идентификатора.

Если инициализатора нет, и спецификатор класса хранения `static` или отсутствует, то это является т.н. *предварительным определением (tentative definition)*. Внутри единицы трансляции может быть несколько *предварительных определений* для одного идентификатора.

Приведу пример из Стандарта C11 (6.9.2/4):

```
int i1 = 1;        //определение, внешняя компоновка
static int i2 = 2; //определение, внутренняя компоновка
extern int i3 = 3; //определение, внешняя компоновка
int i4;            //предварительное определение, внешняя компоновка
static int i5;     //предварительное определение, внутренняя компоновка

int i1;            //предварительное определение, ссылается на предыдущий
int i2;            //ошибка, не совпадает компоновка
int i3;            //предварительное определение, ссылается на предыдущий
int i4;            //предварительное определение, ссылается на предыдущий
int i5;            //ошибка, не совпадает компоновка

extern int i1;     //ссылается на предыдущий с внешней компоновкой
extern int i2;     //ссылается на предыдущий с внутренней компоновкой
extern int i3;     //ссылается на предыдущий с внешней компоновкой
extern int i4;     //ссылается на предыдущий с внешней компоновкой
extern int i5;     //ссылается на предыдущий с внутренней компоновкой
```

Т.е. в Вашем случае (переменная, доступная в разных единицах трансляции) наличие явного `extern` необязательно. А предупреждение выводится для того, чтобы не было ложного ощущения (из-за наличия `extern`), что данная запись является всего лишь объявлением. Хотя на самом деле это определение (из-за наличия инициализатора).

Для закрепления факта константности дополнительно следует добавить `const`. В итоге получим:

```
const int SIZE_A = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Но ведь в сообщении написано, чёрным по  английски: инициализация ВНЕШНЕЙ переменной. Если Вы сами объявили, что данная переменная НЕ Ваша (т.е. она объявлена в другом месте и кем-то другим), то какое Вы имеете право её инициализировать ?! Можно инициализировать чужую жену ? :-)